# How to include Classpath Jars in a war file using Ant

Tags: java, ant, jar, war

I am creating an ant script to build and deploy a project. My project structure is as follows:

```
 Projectname
--src
--tst
--lib ( I have 5 jars here)
--resources
--WebContent
      --META-INF
      --WEB-INF
            --lib (I have 3 jars here)
            --properties
            --templates
            --stylesheets
            --web.xml
```

My requirement is I have to write an ant script to build the project and create a war file in the staging environment (not local). The war should contain all the jar files available in the classpath ( classpath has more than 50 jars).
But when I run my ant script it shows me only 8 jars, that are available in lib folders and does not include the jars from classpath.

How to add classpath while creating a War file? Below is the script I have written for creating a war.

```
<target name="war" description="Bundles the application as a WAR file" depends="build">
            <echo> === PACKAGE WAR ====== </echo>
             <delete dir="target" failonerror="false"/>
             <mkdir dir="target"/>
            <war destfile="target/test.war" needxmlfile="false" >
                <fileset dir="WebRoot">
                    <include name="**/*.*"/>
                </fileset>
                <lib dir ="lib">
                    <include name="**/*.*"/>
                </lib>
<classes dir="WebContent/WEB-INF/classes"/>
            </war>
</target>
```

Classpath is as follows in the ant script.

```
 <property name="ExternalJars.location" value="../ExternalJars"/>
 <path id="Services.classpath">
<fileset dir="lib">
        <include name="**/*.jar"/>
    </fileset>
</path>
```

Comment: I have .classpath in the project does anyone how to use the file while jar -cvf project name.war *  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add  in  task:

`<war destfile="target/test.war" needxmlfile="false" >
      <fileset dir="WebRoot">
          <include name="**/*.*"/>
      </fileset>
      <path>
           <path refid="Services.classpath"/>
      </path>
      <lib dir ="lib">
          <include name="**/*.*"/>
      </lib>
          <classes dir="WebContent/WEB-INF/classes"/>
 </war>`

Comment: Ohoooo,It worked like a charm. Thank you, thank you so much.:) You saved my day. But the thing is the structure of war should be, WEB__INF, MANIFEST.MF and WEB-INF-lib should have all these jars. The above code worked like a charm but it is including the jar files in the base directory with WEB-INF and MANIFEST.MF and not with in WEB-INF-lib.

Comment: Instead of using classpath: <path> <path refid="Services.classpath"/> </path> you can use <zipfileset dir="lib" includes="**/*.jar" prefix="WEB-INF/lib"/> where dir - is your fileset in classpath

Comment: But how would we give reference to services.classpath? to include the classpath jars.

Comment: @user2821894 wrap the path to a `chainedmapper` works, as this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/35694277/2465785

Answer (score 0):

Where is located your 50 jars? Try to add your classpath folder like a  in your  task. Something like this:

`<war destfile="target/test.war" needxmlfile="false" >
      <fileset dir="WebRoot">
          <include name="**/*.*"/>
      </fileset>
      <fileset dir="${classpath_folder}">
          <include name="*.jar"/>
      </fileset>
      <lib dir ="lib">
          <include name="**/*.*"/>
      </lib>
          <classes dir="WebContent/WEB-INF/classes"/>
 </war>`

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. The project has dependencies with some other projects from where it is taking the remaining jars in the classpath

Comment: Do you have this dependencies on the staging environment? How you describes your classpath in Ant?

Comment: The above code did not work as it was saying classpath is not a directory.

Comment: Am describing my classpath as follows: <property name="ExternalJars.location" value="../ExternalJars"/>              <path id="Services.classpath"><fileset dir="lib">
      <include name="**/*.jar"/>
     </fileset>
    </path>

Comment: Try to add in war task element path  :   `<war destfile="target/test.war" needxmlfile="false" >  
      <fileset dir="WebRoot">  
          <include name="**/*.*"/>  
      </fileset>  
      <path>  
     <path refid="Services.classpath"/>  
   </path>  
      <lib dir ="lib">  
          <include name="**/*.*"/>  
      </lib>  
          <classes dir="WebContent/WEB-INF/classes"/>  
 </war>`

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution by using `mappedresources` which a bit uncomfortable but works

```
<war destfile="target/test.war" needxmlfile="false" >
    <fileset dir="WebRoot" />
    <lib dir ="lib" />
    <classes dir="WebContent/WEB-INF/classes"/>

    <mappedresources>
        <path refid="Services.classpath"/>
        <chainedmapper>
            <flattenmapper />
            <globmapper from="*.jar" to="WEB-INF/lib/*.jar" />
        </chainedmapper>
    </mappedresources>
</war>
```